# How to get a dual main nav menu with brand centered on bootstrap 4 wordpress with navwalker

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, wp-nav-walker

I'm trying to create the main navigation menu for a Bootstrap 4 WordPress theme I am working on. I'm but am having a bit of a mare getting the menu to display and hoping someone can help me.

So essentially what I would like is a brand centered image within the nav menu and to have a menu either side of the nav. On collapse, both menus should be visible within the same dropdown. At the moment I can't get the second menu to display.

So far here is where I am, below are snippets from the relevant files. Really appreciate the efforts of anyone who has the time to help.

**Functions.php**

```
// This theme uses wp_nav_menu_left() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'main-left' => esc_html__( 'Main Left', 'wp-bootstrap-starter' ),
) );

// This theme uses wp_nav_menu_righ() in one location.
register_nav_menus( array(
    'main-right' => esc_html__( 'Main Right', 'wp-bootstrap-starter' ),
) );
```

**Navwalker**

```
    <?php

if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
  die( 'Direct access is forbidden.' );
}

if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker' ) ) {

  class WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
  if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
    $t = '';
    $n = '';
  } else {
    $t = "\t";
    $n = "\n";
  }

  $this->dropdown = true;
  $output         .= $n . str_repeat( $t, $depth ) . '<div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">' . $n;
}

/**
 * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
 *
 * @since       1.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker::end_lvl()
 *
 * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 */
public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
  if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
    $t = '';
    $n = '';
  } else {
    $t = "\t";
    $n = "\n";
  }

  $this->dropdown = false;
  $output         .= $n . str_repeat( $t, $depth ) . '</div>' . $n;
}

/**
 * Starts the element output.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker::start_el()
 *
 * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
 * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
 * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
 */
public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
  if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
    $t = '';
    $n = '';
  } else {
    $t = "\t";
    $n = "\n";
  }

  $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

  if ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->attr_title, 'divider' ) && $this->dropdown ) {
    $output .= $indent . '<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>' . $n;
    return;
  } elseif ( 0 === strcasecmp( $item->title, 'divider' ) && $this->dropdown ) {
    $output .= $indent . '<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>' . $n;
    return;
  }

  $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
  $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;
  $classes[] = 'nav-item';

  if ( $args->walker->has_children ) {
    $classes[] = 'dropdown';
  }

  if ( 0 < $depth ) {
    $classes[] = 'dropdown-menu';
  }

  /**
   * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
   *
   * @since 1.2.0
   *
   * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
   * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   */
  $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

  /**
   * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
   *
   * @since 3.0.0
   * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
   *
   * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
   * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
   * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   */
  $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
  $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

  /**
   * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
   *
   * @since 3.0.1
   * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
   *
   * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
   * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
   * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   */
  $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
  $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

  if ( !$this->dropdown ) {
    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names . '>' . $n . $indent . $t;
  }

  $atts           = array();
  $atts['title']  = !empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
  $atts['target'] = !empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
  $atts['rel']    = !empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
  $atts['href']   = !empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';

  /**
   * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
   *
   * @since 3.6.0
   * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
   *
   * @param array $atts {
   *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
   *
   *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
   *     @type string $target Target attribute.
   *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
   *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
   * }
   * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
   * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   */
  $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

  if ( $args->walker->has_children ) {
    $atts['data-toggle']   = 'dropdown';
    $atts['aria-haspopup'] = 'true';
    $atts['aria-expanded'] = 'false';
  }

  $attributes = '';
  foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
    if ( !empty( $value ) ) {
      $value      = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
      $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
    }
  }

  /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
  $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

  /**
   * Filters a menu item's title.
   *
   * @since 4.4.0
   *
   * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
   * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
   * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   */
  $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

  $item_classes = array( 'nav-link' );

  if ( $args->walker->has_children ) {
    $item_classes[] = 'dropdown-toggle';
  }

  if ( 0 < $depth ) {
    $item_classes[] = 'dropdown-item';
  }

  $item_output = $args->before;
  $item_output .= '<a class="' . implode( ' ', $item_classes ) . '" ' . $attributes . '>';
  $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
  $item_output .= '</a>';
  $item_output .= $args->after;

  /**
   * Filters a menu item's starting output.
   *
   * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
   * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
   * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
   *
   * @since 3.0.0
   *
   * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
   * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
   * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
   * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
   */
  $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

/**
 * Ends the element output, if needed.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @see Walker::end_el()
 *
 * @param string   $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
 * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
 * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
 */
public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
  if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
    $t = '';
    $n = '';
  } else {
    $t = "\t";
    $n = "\n";
  }

  $output .= $this->dropdown ? '' : str_repeat( $t, $depth ) . '</li>' . $n;
}

/**
 * Menu Fallback
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 *
 * @param array $args passed from the wp_nav_menu function.
 */
public static function fallback( $args ) {
  if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) {

    $defaults = array(
        'container'       => 'div',
        'container_id'    => false,
        'container_class' => false,
        'menu_class'      => 'menu',
        'menu_id'         => false,
    );
    $args     = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    if ( !empty( $args['container'] ) ) {
      echo sprintf( '<%s id="%s" class="%s">', $args['container'], $args['container_id'], $args['container_class'] );
    }
    echo sprintf( '<ul id="%s" class="%s">', $args['container_id'], $args['container_class'] ) .
    '<li class="nav-item">' .
    '<a href="' . admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' ) . '" class="nav-link">' . __( 'Add a menu' ) . '</a>' .
    '</li></ul>';
    if ( !empty( $args['container'] ) ) {
      echo sprintf( '</%s>', $args['container'] );
    }
  }
}

  }

}
```

**Header.php**

```
        <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark p-0">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>           


            <div class="navbar-brand"><!-- brand centered-->
                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' ) ): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo esc_attr(get_theme_mod( 'wp_bootstrap_starter_logo' )); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ); ?>">
                    </a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <a class="site-title" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' )); ?>"><?php esc_url(bloginfo('name')); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right d-sm-block d-md-none">
                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
            </button>



            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'    => 'main-left',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end',
            'menu_id'         => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-left',
            'depth'           => 3,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ));

            wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location'    => 'main-right',
            'container'       => 'div',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end',
            'menu_id'         => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'navbar-right',
            'depth'           => 3,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'          => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker()
            ));
            ?>

        </nav>
    </div>
```